# Question about open sets in subspace topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let, $A$ and $B$ be sets in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. If $U$ and $V$ are open sets in the subspace topology of $A \cup B$, then are $U \cap A$ and $V \cap A$ necessarily open in the subspace topology of $A$ and $B$ respectively? We are also given that $A \cup B =  U \cup V$.

This is a step in a real analysis proof, I'm just not sure how the author justifies this step. I can't quite see how $U \cap A$ and $V \cap A$ should be open. I think I'm missing something very trivial/easy. Any suggestions would be appreciated?

Comment: The subspace topology $A$ inherits from $\mathbb R^n$ is the same that it inherits from $A\cup B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set is open in the subspace topology of $E$ iff it is of the form $A\cap W$ for some $W$ open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

If $U$ is open in $A\cup B$, it is of the form $W\cap (A\cup B)$ for some $W$ open in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then
$$
A\cap U=A\cap (W\cap (A\cup B))=W\cap A
$$